# Two objects with same data are not the same?

Tags: java, object, compare, equals

I have a test class like so:

```
public class CompareObjects {

public static class Obj {
    public int i;

    public Obj(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Obj o1 = new Obj(0);
    Obj o2 = new Obj(0);

    if(o1 == o2) {
        System.out.println("Equal");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not equal");
    }
}
```

}

I though the test would return "Equal", but it didn't.  Why doesn't Java consider two objects with equal components not the same?  Am I doing something wrong here?  I have a feeling I completely overlooked something when I started learning Java.

Also, I tested the two against each other with the equals() method, and I get the same result.  My reason for this question is that I would like to be able to test an ArrayList with the contains() method to see if one object has the same components as another and therefore equal.  Any ideas?

Comment: one of the most basic things in java is the difference between `equals` and `==`

Comment: Implement your own "equals". == checks to see if they're the same objects, which in this case has nothing to do with their properties.

Comment: @gefei: Yes I know that.  They both return "Not equal" though

Comment: [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/1288408)

Comment: @JBNizet: What benefit do you get for responding like that?

Comment: No benefit at all. You're right, and I apologize. My comment was harsh. I'm just a bit too obsessed about correctness.

Comment: It's all good.  You were right, I didn't REALLY know that.  I just thought I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` compares the *references* to the object. For example:

```
Obj a = new Obj(0);
Obj b = a;
//a == b
```

Try implementing `equals()`:

```
public static class Obj {
    public int i;

    public Obj(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Obj) || other == null) return false;
        return i == ((Obj)other).i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `if(o1.equals(o2)) {`. However, this is not really a good example, read [this (link)](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) for more information.

Comment: Please also override `hashCode()`. Not doing it is a bug.

Comment: @JBNizet that's why I said `However, this is not really a good example`

Answer (score 2):

`==` returns true only if you are comparing the same object [i.e. the same memory location].

If you want to compare objects by their fields, you have to overload the `equals()` method, in order to induce an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) over them.

```
public boolean equals(Object other){

    return this.i == other.i;

}
```

Be sure that the `equals()` method respects reflexivity, symmmetry, transitivity.

Comment: moonwave99 typed faster than me. [this is a good tutorial for overloading equals.](http://code.hammerpig.com/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-java-by-overriding-equals.html)

Comment: Please also override `hashCode()`. Not doing it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares the reference equality, i.e if they refer to the same object in the memory.

You need to override `equals()` method, and use it whenever you want to compare their values. Also, override `hashCode()` which is used by HashMap for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator does not check for equality in class data; rather, it checks to see if they are the same location in memory. If you did `o2 = o1` instead of initializing them the same way, they would be the same location in memory, so `o2==o1` would return `true`. However, since they were initialized some separately, it returns false. Instead, you should define an `equals` method and implement that.